# How to write multidimensinal array php function?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, random

I need to make a function which creates multidimensional array, with adjustable number of rows and columns, and generated random numbers of each row, also adjustable

I have this attempt now, but it seems to go into an infinite loop:

```
function make($length,$start,$end)
{
    if ($length<abs($start-$end)+1){
        for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++){
        while (!isset($array) || count($array)<$length){
            $vel=rand($start,$end);
            if (!isset($array) || !in_array($vel,$array)){
                $array[$i][]=$vel;
            }
        }
        }
    
            return $array;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Please help, I can`t seem to figure it out

Comment: Start with Good code indentation it would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Please show us the function call yo are using, or a few

Comment: What do you actually want the resulting array to look like

Comment: You know, code is a _lot_ easier to read and understand if you leave spaces between the various parts. See how I've edited what you've posted. As RiggsFolly indicated above, it wil make your life easier if you use clear formatting. It will certainly make easier the lives of anyone else who has to read your code, such as us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not checking the right array parts in the loops

```
function make($length,$start,$end)
{
    if ($length<abs($start-$end)+1){
        for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++){
            while (!isset($array[$i]) || count($array[$i])<$length){
//                              ^^^^                 ^^^^
                $vel=rand($start,$end);
                if (!isset($array[$i]) || !in_array($vel,$array[$i])){
//                               ^^^^                          ^^^^
                    $array[$i][]=$vel;
                }
            }
        }
    
        return $array;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

print_r( make(5,10,30) );
```

The RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
            [1] => 16
            [2] => 27
            [3] => 17
            [4] => 26
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 19
            [3] => 25
            [4] => 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 28
            [2] => 20
            [3] => 19
            [4] => 27
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23
            [1] => 17
            [2] => 12
            [3] => 16
            [4] => 15
        )

    [4] => Array (
            [0] => 17
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 22
            [3] => 13
            [4] => 10
        )
)
```